# how to change camera look at point in XNA

Tags: c#, xna, camera, rotation

i want to do racing game, the car drives but i need the camera to follow it, i have creataLookAt matrix named view. i tried to add to the Z posiotion of the camera and the look at point: (speed of the car)*(-1) when the car driving , but it works only if the car drives forwards because when the car turns, the camera still moving forward. I wanted to rotate the camera on the Y axis when the car truns left or right, and here i got stuck.

can anyone tell me how can the camera follow the car?

Comment: Please post some code. Can we move this to GameDev.SE?

Answer (score 2):

You have a matrix that represents the orientation of the car. The camera's position is based off that car matrix like this:

```
CameraPosition = carPosition + (carMatrix.Backward * trailingDistance);
cameraTarget = carPosition;

view = Matrix.Createlookat(cameraPosition, cameraTarget, Vector3.Up);
```

That's a good starting point to make a trailing 3rd person camera.

Comment: Yes, the component vectors you can get from the world matrix are very useful for these sorts of things!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a matrix to transform the vector that you add to the camera's position.  Rotation is just a matter of calculating what angle you need in order to face your target.